# how to support ansible-playbook from python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ansible

we moved to work with `python3` instead with `python2`
but when we try to run `ansible-playbook` VIA `python3` then we get

```
python3 /usr/bin/ansible-playbook .....
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ansible-playbook", line 34, in <module>
    from ansible import context
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ansible'
```

ansible is already installed as we see from pip list

```
pip list | grep ansible
ansible                            2.9.9
```

but not from pip3

```
 pip3 list | grep ansible  ( no output )
```

so in beginning  we was thinking that `ansible` that installed with version `2.9.9` will support also `python3` ( based on https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/python_3_support.html)

but seems this isn't the case

so any suggestion how to run `python3 /usr/bin/ansible-playbook`?

not sure if I say the right approtch

but maybe we need to install the following pkgs to support python3

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  5836841 Dec  1 10:07 ansible-base-2.10.3.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   125774 Dec  1 10:07 Jinja2-2.11.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   269377 Dec  1 10:07 PyYAML-5.3.1.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  2606314 Dec  1 10:07 cryptography-3.2.1-cp35-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    35858 Dec  1 10:07 packaging-20.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    32690 Dec  1 10:07 MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   411052 Dec  1 10:07 cffi-1.14.4-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    10963 Dec  1 10:07 six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    67842 Dec  1 10:07 pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   112041 Dec  1 10:07 pycparser-2.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

I just do the following and pip download ansible with all dependencies

```
 python3 -m pip download ansible
```

Comment: Use `pip3` or even better `python3 -m pip` to install ansible.

Comment: do you mean to download the ansible that fit for python3 as python3 -m pip download ansible

Comment: see please my update

Comment: No, I mean `install`. `download` will just download files. Also you should consider to uninstall the Python 2 ansible or to use a virtual environment to prevent a version mess.

Comment: yes but we need to install it offline we not have network connectivity

Comment: for now we need to support both python2/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more than one version of Python on your system, you can use the python environment:

**Update server :**

sudo apt-get update -y

**Install pip for python3 :**

sudo apt install python3-pip -y

**Force upgrade pip3:**

sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip

**Install virtual environment python3:**

python3 -m pip install virtualenv

**Create virtual environment python3:**

python3 -m venv /tmp/Myenv

**Use isolate virtual environment python3:**

source /tmp/Myenv/bin/activate

**Install ansible in venv python3:**

pip3 install ansible

**Use ansible with venv python3:**

source /tmp/Myenv/bin/activate

ansible-playbook [command]